# Will the java Supplier returns same object at any situation

Tags: java

I am using the Supplier to create the instance of a list whenever the object is required.

```
Supplier<Optional> supplier = ()->Optional.of(new LinkedList<>());
```

Above mentioned supplier is called from RecursiveTask.compute multiple times. on RecursiveTask.compute, Once the supplier.get() is invoked, some objects are added into it.

```
Optional<LinkedList> optList = supplier.get();
optList.get().add("<>");
```

I believe that *supplier.get()* always invoke the *Optional.of(new LinkedList<>())* and return the new object every time it is invoked as like normal Functional interface. Is there any chance that it will return the same instance for multiple calls?.

I am bit confused with below statement mentioned on java docs ([Supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html)).

> There is no requirement that a new or distinct result be returned each
>   time the supplier is invoked

Comment: I think the statement from the java docs says that your implementation of the supplier isn't required to return everytime a different object. In your case, you are however returning a new LinkedList every time you call your supplier.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation you're quoting says it's not a *requirement* to return a distinct value each time... but the supplier you've shown *does* return a distinct value every time.

Yes, calling `supplier.get()` will execute the relevant code each time it's invoked, but it's up to that code as to whether it returns a new instance each time or reuses the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Given your current implementation, a new `Optional` instance will be returned each time the `Supplier`'s `get()` method is invoked.

If you want the same instance to be returned each time you call `get()`, you should create a single instance and have the `Supplier` return it:

```
Optional<LinkedList<SomeThing>> instance = Optional.of(new LinkedList<SomeThing>());
Supplier<Optional> supplier = () -> instance;
```

Given the documentation you quoted, this would be a valid implementation.

Of course, I'm not sure why you'd need to wrap the `LinkedList` with an `Optional` here, since this `Supplier` never produces an empty `Optional`.